# Keeping a clean git history when using gitflow - unmerged commits on develop

Tags: git, gitflow

Using gitflow, when creating a `release-1.0.0` branch and merging it to both `master` and `develop`, both branches will have a missing commit:

- `master` wont have the commit where `release-1.0.0` was merge to `develop`
- `develop` wont have the commit where `release-1.0.0` was merge to `master`

Instead, after `hotfix-1.0.1` is created and merged to `master`, when it is being merged to `develop`, the *commits to merge* will include the previous commit where `release-1.0.0` was merged to `master`; so it will look like this:

```
User 'john doe' is trying to merge the following commits into 'develop' from 'hotfix-1.1.1'.

* merge release-1.0.0 to master
* merge release-1.1.0 to master
* Fix shopping cart critical bug
```

If this sounds confusing, you can easily notice this everytie you see `develop` is usually a couple of commits behind `master` (even though develop, theoretically, should **only** be ahead since it's the main branch. Those commits are merges from `release-x.x.x` to `master`).

How should this be handled to maintain a clean history?

Comment: Please define "clean history".

Comment: Want a clean history? Don't use gitflow. It by definition pollutes your history. Instead, think about what you really need and build a workflow around that, so it actually fits how you want to work.

Comment: The merge to master will be a "copy", no need to merge it to develop. Make hot fixes from the previous release branch, not master, and merge to both from there, and you won't have the problem. Master is not adding much to the model so you can actually drop it completely, IMO.

Comment: @axl I understand what you mean, but I'm trying to follow gitflow as close as possible to it's documentation. I'd rather not doing any kind of "hackz" because since gitflow is already adopted by many many developers, they should already have a solution for this simple thing

Comment: There are several discussions about how to solve various issues with GitFlow on GitHub and other places. Sometimes there just isn't a silver bullet.

Comment: Just 2c: No matter how many devs use it, answer "why?" first for yourself...

Comment: @RomanSusi mostly because it's well documented, community is broad so it doesn't feel like "my own [unrefined] approach" and it if it were not by the problem described in my question, I'd be perfect to be honest; At least for property software development (since we need a well structured methodology, rather than just throwing random PRs from time to time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a good approach is to avoid having two "main" branches, master and develop are kind of redundant. It's explained thoroughly [here](https://barro.github.io/2016/02/a-succesful-git-branching-model-considered-harmful/), branded `cactus-flow` by the author.

Some points stand out as opposed to git-flow:

- Just one main branch
- Only fast-forward merges

For me the last one is important, as after using git-flow for a long time I'm yet to see what's useful about `--no-ff` merges.

> I'm trying to follow gitflow as close as possible to it's
>   documentation. I'd rather not doing any kind of "hackz" because since
>   gitflow is already adopted by many many developers, they should
>   already have a solution for this simple thing

IMHO that's your big mistake. There's no reason for you to stick to git-flow as much as possible. It may be used in thousands of projects but that does not affect yours, does not make it good.

Git-flow is a good starting point but you should think about adapting it to your tools and workflow rather than the other way around.